# Ruby on Rails link_to :method => :delete syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

This is a nub question.  I have a resource `Project` which `has_many` `Feeds`.  When I am viewing the list of nested Feeds on the Project page, I have a `Delete` button to remove that Feed from the Project.  It works with this syntax:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [feed.project, feed], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

But that then directs to the page listing all the Feeds, and I instead want it to redirect back to the Project page the user was just at.  Is it a matter of changing `[feed.project, feed]` or is it something else?  I don't quite understand the syntax of `link_to` well enough yet.

**EDIT:**
In my feeds_controller.rb, I changed the redirect line to `:back`

```
def destroy
project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@feed = project.feeds.find(params[:id])
@feed.destroy
redirect_to :back

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a look at the controller for this resource. It should be somewhere like `app/controllers/projects_controller`, where's there should be an action named `destroy`. The code that do the redirect must be in there. You'll have to change the following line:

```
redirect_to project_feeds_url(project)
```

to this

```
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: The resource to be destroyed is the Feed object, so I went to the feeds_controller.rb and added the redirect into the destroy method.  This errored to: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action.`

Comment: @Paul: That error means you are probably assuming that `redirect_to` (and/or `render`) return out of the controller action... In reality, you need to do something like this: `redirect_to :back and return` (to return from the method immediately afterward).

Comment: @Paul: You shouldn't *add* the `redirect_to :back` line, it must replace the `redirect_to ...` already in the action code.

Comment: @Nicolas, oh I see now.  I was confused by the other comment that added the line directly in. See my edit above for what I have working.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @feed = @project.feeds.find(params[:id])
  @feed.destroy
  redirect_to @project
end
```

Comment: Doing this gives me a `Cannot redirect to nil!` error.  This would be in my feeds_controller correct?  The page that I'm looking at when I click the delete button is something like `http://localhost:3000/projects/1`.  Is it still the feed controller because it is a feed object?